# Flow Router doesn't work with ObjectID. Any fix?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to build routes in my Meteor app. Routing works perfectly fine but getting information from db with route path just doesn't work. I create my page specific routes with this:

```
FlowRouter.route('/level/:id'...
```

This route takes me to related template without a problem. Then I want to get some data from database that belong to that page. In my template helpers I get my page's id with this:

```
var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
```

This gets the `ObjectID()` but in string format. So I try to find that `ObjectID()` document in the collection with this:

```
Levels.findOne({_id: id});
```

But of course documents doesn't have ObjectIDs in string format (otherwise we wouldn't call it "object"id). Hence, it brings an undefined error. I don't want to deal with creating my own `_id`s so is there anything I can do about this?

PS: Mongo used to create `_id`s with plain text. Someting like I would get with `_id._str` now but all of a sudden, it generates `ObjectID()`. I don't know why, any ideas?

Comment: MongoDB used `ObjectId`s by default as far back as I can remember (pre-2.4), and Meteor explicitly sets GUID strings by default. Perhaps you inserted using a `meteor shell` in the past and now used a mongo shell/GUI or a `meteor mongo` prompt to do so, which resulted in `ObjectId`s. Is there any reason for not creating the data again from the meteor shell/code and avoid this issue altogether?

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem immediately. If you write this comment as an answer, I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB used ObjectIds as `_id`s by default and Meteor explicitly sets GUID strings by default.

Perhaps you inserted using a `meteor shell` session in the past and now used a mongo shell/GUI or a `meteor mongo` prompt to do so, which resulted in `ObjectId`s being created.

If this happens in a development environment, you could generate the data again.

Otherwise, you could try to generate new `_id`s for your data using `Meteor.uuid()`.

If you want to use `ObjectId` as the default for a certain collection, you can specify the [`idGeneration`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection) option to its constructor as `'MONGO'`.

If you have the string content of an `ObjectId` and want to convert it, you can issue

```
let _id = new Mongo.ObjectID(my23HexCharString);
```