# Problems with ObjectID in updating collection

Tags: meteor

I have the following code:

```
Meteor.methods({
    inPlay: function (id) {
        alert(id);
        playersCollection.update({_id: id},{
            $set: {
                age : 30, 
                username : "Jack"
            }
        });
    }
});
```

However the above method won't work. The document id is currently in the form of ObjectId("3454....."), and if I change the selector from `_id` to other property like `name` then it will work, but I need to use ObjectID.

I have tried many things but nothing works! Any idea?

Comment: You'll get the `ObjectId()` format if you do a direct insert from the mongo console. If you insert via meteor you'll get a normal meteor `_id` and your code will then work.

Comment: There have been some related questions. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35712679/268093) to one of them. You could either recreate the documents, convert the ids into strings or use `new Mongo.ObjectID()` to create the matching `objectId` from a string.

Comment: why just don't use toString?