# Querying objectId in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, objectid

I recently started to load mongodb using mongoimport and realized that it has added an `ObjectId` field associated with the `"_id"`. When I query this using the "meteor mongo" commandline it works fine:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.Warehouses.find({"_id":ObjectId("571b7a89a990b5b8779b1315")})    
{ "_id" : ObjectId("571b7a89a990b5b8779b1315"), "name" : "Stephan Lumber", "street" : "23 East St", "city" : "Plano", "state" : "TX"}
meteor:PRIMARY>
```

My code can read the value in `"_id"` using `console.log( "id ", currentId)`

It returns `ObjectID("571b7a89a990b5b8779b1315")`

the value `currentId` contains the current warehouse ID selected.

However, when I try to use this to access the data in the code I keep getting "undefined" errors. I have tried many different ways. Here are a few:

1. `warehouse = Warehouses.findOne({"_id":Mongo.ObjectID(currentId)});`
2. `warehouse = Warehouses.findOne({"_id":ObjectId(currentId)});`

Also for some reason "ObjectId" in not recognized on the latter.

I don't know what else to try. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure but `console.log( "id ", currentId)` returns `ObjectID("571b7a89a990b5b8779b1315")` doesn't make sense to me?

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35712679/268093) help (using `new`)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add anything like Mongo.ObjectID or ObjectId you just have to write directly currentId.

```
warehouse = Warehouses.findOne({"_id": currentId});
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, that was one of the first things I tried and I still get "undefined". To make sure I wasn't loosing my mind, I just tested it again and it still returns "undefined". What I wound up having to be was a bit hacky:

Comment: var warehouseStringID = currentId.slice(currentId.indexOf('"') + 1, -2); 

const warehouse = Warehouses.findOne({_id: new Mongo.ObjectID(warehouseStringID)});

Comment: Ddi you try Warehouses.findOne(currentId), I have done this CollectionName.remove(mongoObjectId) in one of my demo and thats worked for me.